# Forcing HttpClient to use Content-Type: text/xml

Tags: c#, httpclient

This is driving me nuts, I am setting the ContentType header everywhere I can and can't seem to make it stop sending text/plain.

Watching the data in Fiddler, the request is always requesting:

POST http:/domain.com HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://domain.com");
        request.Content = new StringContent(Serialize(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        request.Content.Headers.Clear();
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
        request.Headers.Clear();
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/xml");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        return  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 21):

It looks like you tried to hard :) This should just work.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://domain.com");
    request.Content = new StringContent(Serialize(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: It should, but it's not. I started with simple attempts like that. Did you check the output in Fiddler?

Comment: Yep, I did. What platform do you use? I tried ConsoleApplication with .NET Framework (on Desktop)

Comment: Beware of the "using" statement with HttpClient.  See "[You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)" article.

Comment: Ye this answer doesn't work, no idea why it's the top answer?

Comment: This is a 7 years old answer. I assume .net has changed a lot since then

Comment: i used this "application/xml" instead of text/xml

Answer (score 10):

Try settings the default request headers:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
```

Comment: no, tried that. But Accept header wouldn't help. I'm trying to set the Content-Type header

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use "application/xml" instead of "text/xml"