# Fetch XML via HttpClient and populate a List<>

Tags: c#, xml, rss, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to fetch XML data from an RSS feed using the C# HttpClient and fill a `List<RssFeedItem>` with the data. This code is from another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974110/177416):

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://domain.com");
    request.Content = new StringContent(Serialize(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The `RssFeedItem` class is as follows:

```
public class RssFeedItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ContentSnippet { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
}
```

I've written the following method to fetch and populate a `List<RssFeedItem>`, but don't know how to actually implement the HttpClient call and use its data.

```
public static List<RssFeedItem> ReadFeed(string url)
{
    //create a new list of the rss feed items to return
    List<RssFeedItem> rssFeedItems = new List<RssFeedItem>();

    // ****** fetch the RSS feed here as XML... ******

    //use a dataset to retrieve the rss feed
    using (DataSet rssData = new DataSet())
    {
        //read the xml from the stream of the web request
        rssData.ReadXml(rssFeed.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        //loop through the rss items in the dataset and populate the list of rss feed items
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in rssData.Tables["item"].Rows)
        {
            rssFeedItems.Add(new RssFeedItem
            {
                ContentSnippet = Convert.ToString(dataRow(["contentsnippet"])),
                Content = Convert.ToString(dataRow["content"]),
                PubDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow["pubDate"]),
                Title = Convert.ToString(dataRow["title"])
            });
        }
    }

    //return the rss feed items
    return rssFeedItems;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: It doesn't have to be a `List` object. Please suggest if there's an efficient way use the data to loop over in Razor. Thanks :)

**UPDATE 2**: Here's a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:s="http://jadedpixel.com/-/spec/shopify">
    <id>http://example.com/blogs/news.atom</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://example.com/blogs/news.atom"/>
    <title>News</title>
    <updated>2015-05-14T08:48:00-04:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Author</name>
    </author>
    <entry>
        <id>http://example.com/blogs/news/28298241-sixth-post</id>
        <published>2015-05-14T08:48:00-04:00</published>
        <updated>2015-05-14T08:48:49-04:00</updated>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news./28298241-sixth-post"/>
        <title>Sixth Post</title>
        <author>
            <name>Author</name>
        </author>
        <content type="html">
            <![CDATA[Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. <br><br>Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim.]]>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>http://example.com/blogs/news/28297985-fifth-post</id>
        <published>2015-05-14T08:48:00-04:00</published>
        <updated>2015-05-14T08:48:16-04:00</updated>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news/28297985-fifth-post"/>
        <title>Fifth Post</title>
        <author>
            <name>Author</name>
        </author>
        <content type="html">
            <![CDATA[Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. <br><br>Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales. Aenean lectus elit, fermentum non, convallis id, sagittis at, neque. Nullam mauris orci, aliquet et, iaculis et, viverra vitae, ligula. Nulla ut felis in purus aliquam imperdiet. Maecenas aliquet mollis lectus. Vivamus consectetuer risus et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet.]]>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>http://example.com/blogs/news/28297665-fourth-post</id>
        <published>2015-05-14T08:47:00-04:00</published>
        <updated>2015-05-14T08:47:43-04:00</updated>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news/28297665-fourth-post"/>
        <title>Fourth Post</title>
        <author>
            <name>Author</name>
        </author>
        <content type="html">
            <![CDATA[Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. <br><br>Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla.]]>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: can you please provide at least a single rssfeed element within and with the whole xml style, 'coz this is required to create some code, please...

Comment: @cramopy: I'm working on that right now. Give me a sec...

Comment: @cramopy: please see above for the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
// ****** fetch the RSS feed here as XML... ******
```

with:

```
string result;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

XmlReader rssFeed = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result));
```

Comment: Thanks, @achitaka-san. What is the `obj` referring to in the above code? I'm not able to resolve that.

Comment: Somenthing you need to send to server to get an answer. If nothing then just skip the line.

Comment: Thanks, @achitaka-san. How do I populate the list using the XML data?