# XML deserialization: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1 position 1. Tried almost everything

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to deserialize XML. I'm getting the XML to string(which works fine) but then when I try to parse it I'm getting and error **"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1 position 1"**
I tried everything which I found here. Read a lot of threads and tried all the suggestion: reading this to byte array, to stream, trying different Xml classes, removing BOM.

Here is my code(you can see the XML file under the link in code):

```
public class XmlParser
{
    private List<CurrencyUnit> _currenciesList = new List<CurrencyUnit>();
    public List<CurrencyUnit> CurrenciesList { get => _currenciesList; set => _currenciesList = value; }

    public async void GetXML()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A/");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(response);

        foreach (var element in xDocument.Descendants("Rate"))
        {
            CurrencyUnit unit = new CurrencyUnit();

            unit.Currency = element.Element("Currency").Value.ToString();
            unit.Code = element.Element("Code").Value.ToString();
            unit.Mid = element.Element("Mid").Value.ToString();
            CurrenciesList.Add(unit);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is part of the XML(you can see whole under the link from code):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfExchangeRatesTable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ExchangeRatesTable>
<Table>A</Table>
<No>056/A/NBP/2018</No>
<EffectiveDate>2018-03-20</EffectiveDate>
<Rates>
<Rate>
<Currency>bat (Tajlandia)</Currency>
<Code>THB</Code>
<Mid>0.1100</Mid>
</Rate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That endpoint returns JSON if the request headers don't explicitly ask for XML, and you can't parse JSON as XML.

Your browser sends something like `Accept: text/html,[...]application/xml` by default, whereas `HttpClient` sends none. In that case, you get JSON in return. You could've seen this if you'd inspected the `response` variable while debugging.

Either deserialize the response into JSON, or pass the `Accept: application/xml` request header as explained in [Forcing HttpClient to use Content-Type: text/xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973524/forcing-httpclient-to-use-content-type-text-xml).

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```